What is the meaning of "Svadhyaya"?
I know "svadhyaya" is usually translated as "self-study".
But does it mean studying something on your own, without a Guru. Or studying one's own self, as in inner reflection/meditation.

svādhyāya is a synonym of japa and adhyayana, and adhyayana of Veda, is done under a guru only. Svādhyāya of a śāstra (such as āgama, śruti, etc.) is preceded by its śravaṇa, furthermore svādhyāya is preceded by anusandhāna of the artha of mantras, etc.
